# react-native use FCM push notification IOS & Android

Tags: push-notification, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I follow this Link: https://rnfirebase.io/in-app-messaging/usage  But not working.

Now i create token but not receive any notification **messaging().onMessage()** use method

Comment: Hi kevin, you need to explain the question in a more clear way, with steps of reproduction, snapshot or log of the error you are getting.

Comment: Now i create token but not receive any notification
Right now use  messaging().onMessage() method